# Multi-lined ttk styled text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can you make a `ScrolledText` widget (more than one line) with ttk styling in tkinter?

I tried `ttk.Text`, but got this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Text'

Comment: What do you mean by "ScrolledText" widget? Are you literally asking about a multiline text editor widget? How would styling help in such a case? A text widget is just a background color with a small border. What sort of style do you want to apply to it?

Comment: @BryanOakley I want it to look like a normal `ttk.Entry`, but be multiline.

Comment: Why not just use `tkinter.Text` class?

Comment: @Nae `tkinter.Entry` does not look as 'nice' as `ttk.Entry`